# Are host name and server name same?

Tags: networking

I'm learning networking where there are some frequent words like "Host name" , "Server name" . Do host name and server name mean the same thing?

Comment: id say yes they are the same

Comment: depends on the used context. host name just means the name of the host. server is also a host ......

Comment: Probably the same ... see here http://superuser.com/questions/887173/what-is-a-hostname-versus-a-computer-name-versus-a-subdomain-versus-www for some more reading

Comment: please post such type of issue at below link: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not necessarily the same. Multiple servers (in the sense of binaries that respond to network communication, e.g. a web server, a mail server) can run on the same host (in the sense of a physical or virtual machine). But it depends upon the context as to exactly what is meant by "server name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the networking (or internetworking) world the term `host` is generally used for every device which has *a network card (`NIC` - Network Interface Controller) attached to a given network*, as it *"hosts"* this card.

The `server` is in this context a *hardware* (computer) running a *server program*  - in most cases as a service (Windows) or deamon (UNIX, Linux). This program - as suggests its name - provide some kind of *services for other computers* (more precisely, for other *programs*, because they may be on the *same* computer as the sever program is) named *clients*.

The server *listens* to clients as they send *requests* to it. The server *serves* their requests - it sends back *answers*.  The notoriously known example is an *e-mail server* and an *e-mail client*.

So the term `host` is used for both the *server's and client's computers* as both are *hosting* a network card.

`Server name` is in this context only a particular case of the `host name` because *both the server and the client are `hosts`*.